# Overiding Save button not catching trigger errors

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have created my own save process, and i am trying to catch trigger errors that occur, but instead what is happening is that it just fails to save instead and continues the redirect. I want it to just error the page and stop the redirect. This is the code i am currently using it doesnt seem to be working. All variables have been assigned currently.

```
public pageReference saveRedirect()
    {
        try
        {
            controller.save();
            PageReference pageRef = new PageReference(ReturnURL);
            return pageRef;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ApexPages.addMessages(e);
         return null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: How are you handling the errors in the trigger?

Comment: trigger.addErrors, in the default Save from the controller the errors work fine. It is just when i use the custom save to do some redirect trickery it redirects without failing the trigger, but it also does not save the record

Comment: What is the value of **returnURL**?  If it is the Id of the record, you could just do **return controller.save();**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (null==controller.save())
{
   return null;
}
return PageRef;
```

This snippet fixed it

Comment: Makes sense as the save method returns you a PageReference